# Style option not getting applied on html-to-img

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to use the html-to-img package to download an image.
The style option that I pass into the call doesn't seem to be being applied.

Not sure if this is a bug with html-to-img... or if I'm doing something wrong.

Looking for anyone with experience with that package, who is willing to lend a hand...

Code recreating problem can be seen here...
https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-surf-0kc42?file=/pages/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by making position static in the options... top and left options didnt work

```
htmlToImage
    .toPng(element, {
      backgroundColor: "white",
      style: {
        position: "static"
      },
    })
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.download = "chart.png";
      link.href = dataUrl;
      link.click();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use html2canvas instead?

```
import html2canvas from "html2canvas"

html2canvas(element).then((canvas) => {
  const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL()
  const link = document.createElement("a")
  link.download = "myDownload.png"
  link.href = dataURL
  link.click()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### The reason

It won't show in your downloaded image because browser doesn't render it.

#### Possible solutions

You can make some fast animation, print it and then move back, for example.

Or, you can use canvas and then download the canvas.